# Draw arrow between on line between two points

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, gdi+

how can i draw an arror to show the direction of line ? i manage to do but the arrow not in the right shape. [image]

```
//For Line
Point point1 = new Point(100, 110);
Point point2 = new Point(300, 210);
Point point3 = new Point(200, 310);
Point point4 = new Point(100,310); 

e.Graphics.DrawLines(pen, points);

//For Arrow
e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, 200, 150, 180, 130);
e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, 200, 150, 180, 150);
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. If all you're doing is hard-coding the coordinates, then just hard-code the _correct_ coordinates. If you want some kind of computed arrow, then you need to provide more detail in your question. This includes a [mcve] that shows what you've tried, and a detailed explanation of what _specifically_ it is you need help with.

Comment: I think the question is clear. How do you add arrow features to a `GDI` drawn line in windows forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another example:

[image]

Produced by:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Point[] points = {
        new Point(100, 110),
        new Point(300, 210),
        new Point(200, 310),
        new Point(100, 310)
    };
    for(int i=0; i<(points.Length-1); i++)
    {
        Point p1 = points[i];
        Point p2 = points[i + 1];                
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, p1, p2);

        float angle = getAngle(p1, p2);
        Point mid = getMidPoint(p1, p2);
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(mid.X, mid.Y);
        e.Graphics.RotateTransform(angle);
        e.Graphics.RotateTransform(135);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, new Point(0, 0), new Point(8, 0));
        e.Graphics.RotateTransform(-270);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, new Point(0, 0), new Point(8, 0));
        e.Graphics.ResetTransform();
    }
}

private float getAngle(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    float deltaX = p2.X - p1.X;
    float deltaY = p2.Y - p1.Y;
    return (float)(Math.Atan2(deltaY, deltaX) * 180.0 / Math.PI);
}

private Point getMidPoint(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    return new Point((p1.X + p2.X)/2,(p1.Y+p2.Y)/2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

[image: draw]

and here is the code to do it:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        this.pictureBox1.Paint += PictureBox1_Paint;
    }

    private void PictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            DrawLineWithArrow(e.Graphics,
                Color.Blue,
                new PointF(50, 50),
                new PointF(340, 120+35*i),
                4f+3f*i, false);
            DrawLineWithArrow(e.Graphics,
                Color.Red,
                new PointF(340, 120+35*i),
                new PointF(340+290, 50),
                4f+3f*i, true);
        }

    }

    public void DrawLineWithArrow(Graphics g, Color color, PointF start, PointF end, float arrowSize=8f, bool filled = false)
    {
        if (start==end) return;

        PointF mid = new PointF((start.X+end.X)/2, (start.Y+end.Y)/2);

        float angle = (float)(180/Math.PI*Math.Atan2(end.Y-start.Y, end.X-start.X));

        var gp = new GraphicsPath();
        gp.AddLines(
            new PointF[] 
            {
                new PointF(-arrowSize, -arrowSize/3),
                new PointF(0, 0),
                new PointF(-arrowSize, arrowSize/3)
            }
        );
        if (filled)
        {
            gp.CloseFigure();
        }
        var state = g.Save();
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(color, 0)) 
        {
            g.DrawLine(pen, start, end);
            g.TranslateTransform(
                mid.X,
                mid.Y);
            g.RotateTransform(angle);
            if (filled)
            {
                using (Brush fill = new SolidBrush(color))
                {
                    g.FillPath(fill, gp);
                }
            }
            g.DrawPath(pen, gp);
        }
        g.Restore(state);
    }
}
```

I took advantage of `Graphics.TranslateTransform()` and `Graphics.RotateTransform()` to move and align the coordinate system in the middle of the line and along the line. The drawing of the arrow is much simpler than trying to do vector rotations by hand.