# How to draw a line with an arrow on a graph?

Tags: c#, graph

How to draw a line with an arrow on a graph in C#? We need did like this but in C#.
[image]

I need to take data from the database for this graph one column at a time and present it as a graph in the picture

I know how to draw a blue line from above, but I don’t understand what to use for the bottom graph

Comment: You might be interested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64021360/2330053).

Comment: What data from the lines do you have? Do you have both endpoints?...or maybe a start point, angle and distance?

Comment: i know start point always equal 0 and line start always from 0.i have this code on VB ,if you want i can send

Comment: i have angle from column in sql . Distance always equal  one  value

Answer (score 0):

Here's a C# WinForms example that you can hopefully dissect and figure out how to use for your situation:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private int lineLength = 250;
    private int arrowLength = 12;
    private List<int> angles = new List<int>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        angles.AddRange(new int[] { 12, 27, -5, 45, -32, -15, 34 });
    }
    private void pictureBox1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;

        // Draw x and y axis for reference:
        ResetCartesianCoordSystem(pb, g);
        Point center = new Point(pb.Width / 2, pb.Height / 2);
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, 0, center.Y, 0, -center.Y);
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, -center.X, 0, center.X, 0);

        foreach (int angle in angles)
        {
            DrawArrowAt(pb, g, new Point(0, 0), angle, lineLength, Color.Red);
        }
    }

    private void ResetCartesianCoordSystem(PictureBox pb, Graphics g)
    {
        g.ResetTransform();
        // Translate origin to center of PB and invert the y-axis:
        Point center = new Point(pb.Width / 2, pb.Height / 2);
        g.TranslateTransform(center.X, center.Y);
        g.ScaleTransform(1.0f, -1.0f);
    }

    private void DrawArrowAt(PictureBox pb, Graphics g, Point pt, int angle, int length, Color c)
    {
        ResetCartesianCoordSystem(pb, g);
        // Move to the Start Point of the Line:
        g.TranslateTransform(pt.X, pt.Y);
        // Rotate the Surface:
        g.RotateTransform(angle);
        using (Pen p = new Pen(c))
        {
            // Draw the Line:
            g.DrawLine(p, 0, 0, lineLength, 0);
            // Move to the End Point of the Line:
            g.TranslateTransform(lineLength, 0);
            // Rotate the Surface for the Left side of the Arrow:
            g.RotateTransform(135);
            // Draw Left side of the Arrow:
            g.DrawLine(p, 0, 0, arrowLength, 0);
            // Rotate the Surface for the Right side of the Arrow:
            g.RotateTransform(-270);
            // Draw Right side of the Arrow:
            g.DrawLine(p, 0, 0, arrowLength, 0);
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

[image]